# Mapping FormGroup to Interface Object

Tags: typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I've been attempting to bind form data in my angular HTML template to an interface in my Component.

I've been following the below tutorial, but my FormGroup is not auto-casting to the interface on the back-end as the tutorial does.

- [Reactive Forms Tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive)

My code is as follows:

---

### Component

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { DeckBuildRequest } from "../domain-models/interfaces/deckBuildRequest.interface";

@Component({
  selector: "deck-options",
  templateUrl: "./deck-options.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./deck-options.component.css"]
})
export class DeckOptionsComponent {
  private deckBuildRequest: FormGroup;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.deckBuildRequest = formBuilder.group({
      "deckSize": 60,
      "deckColors": formBuilder.array([
          {color: "Blue", checked: false},
          {color: "Green", checked: false},
          {color: "Red", checked: false},
          {color: "White", checked: false},
          {color: "Black", checked: false},
          {color: "Colorless", checked: false}
        ])
    });
  }

  GenerateDeck(request: DeckBuildRequest) {
    alert(request.deckSize);
  }

}
```

### HTML

```html
<div id="deck-options">
      <form [formGroup]="deckBuildRequest"
            (ngSubmit)="GenerateDeck(deckBuildRequest)">
        <span>
          <label><input formControlName="deckSize" type="number" max="100" min="1">Number of Cards</label>
        </span>
        <div>
          <label [attr.for]="'color'+i"
            *ngFor="let colorOption of deckBuildRequest.controls['deckColors'].controls, let i = index"
          >
            <input 
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="color{{i}}"
                  value="{{colorOption.value.color}}"
                  ng-checked="colorOption.value.checked"
            />
            {{colorOption.value.color}}
          </label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Generate Deck!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

### Interface

```typescript
export interface DeckBuildRequest {
    deckSize: number;
    deckColors: [{
        color: string;
        checked: boolean;
    }];
}
```

---

What am I missing here?

Comment: *"I've been following the below tutorial, but my FormGroup is not auto-casting to the interface on the back-end as the tutorial does.*". I didn't understand what it means... in fact, what's the problem? Also, what's `ng-checked`?

Comment: @developer033 - From what I gather, you can implicitly map your Form structure provided by the View (HTML) back to the Controller side (Component) by triggering an OnSubmit(..) call, passing along your Form as the parameter, and consuming it on the Controller side via an Interface.  
  
Is this correct or am I off base?

`ng-checked` is forcibly setting the checkboxes to be unchecked on start time.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, I got the implicit mappings to work. You can pass along the value of the formGroup from the View and implicitly cast to an interface on the Component side.

Simply pass along the FormGroup structure values by calling ".getRawValue()" or ".value" to the Component that expects an interface as a parameter to implicitly cast.

Html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit(Form.value)"> ... </form>
```

component.ts

```
submit(instance: ObjectClass){
 console.log(instance); // just to check if it worked 
}
```

There is one important distinction between ".getRawValue()" and ".value" is that getRawValue returns values from disabled controls while value only returns values from controls that are enabled.

Comment: This link now redirects to a Windows PC Repair site

Comment: formobject.getRawValue(); is worked for me thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
(ngSubmit)="GenerateDeck(deckBuildRequest.getRawValue())"
```

Replace this on form html. it's work for me.